# Re-Type object of functions expressions, skipping the first function argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I currently have the following variable

```js
const storePattern = {
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {
    modal: {
      actions: {
        openModal(store, name: string): boolean {
          console.log('Opening Modal', name);
          return true;
        },
        closeModal(store, name: string): boolean {
          console.log('Closing Modal', name);
          return true;
        },
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**Present:** Currently the types for `storePattern.modules.modal.actions` are

```js
(property) actions: {
    openModal(store: any, name: string): boolean;
    closeModal(store: any, name: string): boolean;
}
```

**Goal:** I wish to re-define the types so it skips the first argument and becomes:

```
(property) actions: {
    openModal(name: string): boolean;
    closeModal(name: string): boolean;
}
```

I've gotten the following to work if `actions` was a standalone variable

```
const actions = {
  openModal(store, name: string): boolean {
    console.log('Opening Modal', name);
    return true;
  },
  closeModal(store, name: string): boolean {
    console.log('Closing Modal', name);
    return true;
  }
}

type TypedActions = {
  [Property in keyof typeof actions]: (arg: Parameters<typeof actions[Property]>[1]) => ReturnType<typeof actions[Property]>;
}
```

However the same solution against the `storePattern` object doesn't work.

```
type StorePattern = {
  state: any;
  getters: any;
  mutations: any;
  actions: {
    [ModuleProperty in keyof typeof storePattern['modules'] as ModuleProperty]: {
      [ActionProperty in keyof typeof storePattern['modules'][ModuleProperty]['actions']]: (arg: Parameters<typeof storePattern['modules'][ModuleProperty]['actions'][ActionProperty]) => ReturnType<typeof storePattern['modules'][ModuleProperty]['actions'][ActionProperty]>;
    }
  };
};
```

```
Type '{ modal: { actions: { openModal(store: any, name: string): boolean; closeModal(store: any, name: string): boolean; }; }; }[ModuleProperty]["actions"][ActionProperty]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type '{ modal: { actions: { openModal(store: any, name: string): boolean; closeModal(store: any, name: string): boolean; }; }; }[ModuleProperty]["actions"][keyof { modal: { ...; }; }[ModuleProperty]["actions"]]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
    Type '{ modal: { actions: { openModal(store: any, name: string): boolean; closeModal(store: any, name: string): boolean; }; }; }[ModuleProperty]["actions"][string] | { ...; }[ModuleProperty]["actions"][number] | { ...; }[ModuleProperty]["actions"][symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
      Type '{ modal: { actions: { openModal(store: any, name: string): boolean; closeModal(store: any, name: string): boolean; }; }; }[ModuleProperty]["actions"][string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
```

I'm still learning typescript so my approach isn't clean, happy to take any feedback as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after:

```
  type StorePatternModules = typeof storePattern['modules'];

  type StorePattern = {
    state: any;
    getters: any;
    mutations: any;
    actions: {
      [TModule in keyof StorePatternModules]: {
          [TModuleKey in keyof StorePatternModules[TModule]]: {
            [K in keyof StorePatternModules[TModule][TModuleKey]]: (arg: Parameters<StorePatternModules[TModule][TModuleKey][K]>[1]) => ReturnType<StorePatternModules[TModule][TModuleKey][K]>
          }
      }
    };
  };
```